# Unable to hover my quadcopter

Tags: quadcopter, multi-rotor, radio-control

I'm currently flying a f450 Quadcopter using a APM 2.6 flight controller.While i am able to get the quad off the ground and relatively steady horizontally(via the use of trims).However, i am unable to get the quad to hover no matter what i do.I've tried using trims on throttle,but i am still unable to get it hover.On my transmitter (WFLY WFT06II), where the throttle has "ticks", i am currently stuck between too little lift and too much lift, where i push the throttle up by 1 "tick" and the quad goes from slowly decending to ascending, and vice versa.

Is there any way i can get my quad to hover ( with my hands off the throttle if possible), as currently, evern with me trying to fly it, i can never get it to hover vertically as it alternates between ascending and descending whenever i fiddle with the throttle.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a hack, but you could add a small amount of weight to it so the tick that makes the quad ascend slightly would now be the hover tick.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is impossible in any practical sense; you are trying to perfectly balance the weight of your quadcopter with the force from the thrusters -- without any sensor input.  99.99999% of the possible values you could set for your throttle are either too high or too low, and the correct value may change over time.

To make your quadcopter maintain a constant height, you will need to look at PID control.  For that, you will need some form of altitude sensor and possibly an accelerometer (depending on what sort of accuracy you need).

Answer (score 0):

Ian's comment is spot on. To maintain a constant altitude, you need to know what altitude you are at. For aircraft this is based on a pressure sensor. This is generalized at 14.696 psi for 0 ft altitude. For quad copters this is probably impractical. An ultra sonic sensor pointing at the ground or accelerometers tuned to minimize drift in altitude is more practical if you are relying on visual feedback for adjustment.